Why can’t I do any type of transaction with my Solana?
I use Coinbase and I can see my Solana balance there but I can’t trade, sell, bridge or do anything with it.  I’m new to this world so any advice would be helpful. It reads that my Solana is on the Solana network but I only see my balance on Coinbase.
